# How-To: Bridge 2 Pins Without Soldering

Tags: soldering, bridge

I need to bridge two pairs of pins together on an Xbox 360 AV adapter, and the most common method is to solder them together (to fix a rebooting issue). I don't mind doing this, but I'd like to create a video tutorial for other 360 owners that have the same problem, and not every 360 owner knows how to solder.

With that said, is there a way to bridge a connection without soldering (in a way that's easy enough for everyday folks).

Here's a picture of the AV Adapter (minus the casing so you can see the wires and pins)

[image]

Image courtesy of [this guide I found](http://forums.xbox-scene.com/index.php?/topic/691179-3rd-party-xbox-360-hdmi-av-cable-guide/) for what pins to solder.

Answer (score 1):

If there are holes in pins - you can put piece of uninsulated copper wire inside and jam it hard with aluminium foil ball/balls.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, maybe some sort of silver paint, conductive epoxy, some other conductive goop.  It depends on how much current.  How good a connection do you need.  You'll have to do some tests.  (Personally I like solder, 60/40 with rosin flux core.)